How can I focus HTML elements in WebView inside AndroidView in Jetpack Compose using d-pad remote control in Android TV?
I am developing an Android TV app with Jetpack Compose. On the video player screen, I have a "YouTubePlayer" composable, which has an "AndroidView" composable in it. That AndroidView must show a FrameLayout which wraps a WebView, which loads a page with an embedded YouTube video using iframe API.
I need to get a rectangle on the "Skip ad" button and let the user move focus to other buttons of the page using the remote controller
I came over using "FocusRequester", using a "remember", adding it to the AndroidView using "focusRequester" modifier and calling "requestFocus" to give focus to "AndroidView" but that did not work. Not only that, but I then called "requestFocus()" on the WebView itself and that kind of worked, but only on the emulator. I tested it on two different devices, and got two different results. On the first no rectangle was shown and on the second I got a rectangle around the whole WebView and never to its content.
I then set "isFocusable" on the WebView and got the same result.
I have my "YouTubePlayer" composable inside a "Box" as follows. I have removed details for simplicity:
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

Box(modifier = Modifier
.dPadEvents(player,videoPlayerState,viewModel.adState,focusManager)  .fillMaxSize()
.focusRequester(focusRequester)
.focusable()) {
    YoutubePlayer(
        onAdFinish: {
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
    )
}

The content of YoutubePlayer. Not showing all parameters. Inside I have remembered a listener, which notifies me about some events.
YoutubePlayer(onAdFinish: () -> Unit = {},
focusRequester: FocusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }) {
var youtubePlayerViewWrapper: YouTubePlayerWrapper? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
val listener = remember {
        object: AbstractYouTubePlayerListener(){
            override fun onStateChange(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer, state: PlayerConstants.PlayerState) {
                onStateChange(state)
            }

            override fun onAdStarted() {
                onAdStarted()
                outerFocusRequester.freeFocus()
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
                youtubePlayerViewWrapper?.requestFocus()
            }

            override fun onAdCompleted() {
                onAdFinish()
                focusRequester.freeFocus()
                youtubePlayerViewWrapper?.clearFocus()
            }
        }
    }

AndroidView(factory = {
        youtubePlayerViewWrapper = YouTubePlayerWrapper(it)
        youtubePlayerViewWrapper!!
    }, modifier = modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
        onRelease = {
            it.release()
            it.removeAllViews()
        }
    )


}

"YouTubePlayerWrapper" is a custom view, extending FrameLayout. Inside I have my WebView. I made it this way because I need to recreate the WebView each time a new video will be played, but AndroidView won't allow me to replace the view on recomposition, only update it.
